# Create controller in Yii Framework

Tags: php, yii

i create new controller in yii look like this:

```
class LanguageController extends Controller
{

    public function actionSwitchLanguage($language)
    {
        Yii::app()->session = $language;
        $this->redirect(Yii::app()->request->urlReferrer);
    }
}
```

in views file, i create new url look like this:

```
<a href="<?php echo Yii::app()->controller->createUrl('Language/actionSwitchLanguage',array('language'=>'en')); ?>">English</a>
```

but when clicking the link, it appears error:

```
Error 404
The system is unable to find the requested action "actionswitchlanguage".
```

somebody can help me?

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
<a href="<?php echo Yii::app()->controller->createUrl('Language/switchLanguage',array('language'=>'en')); ?>">English</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

No need to add `action` in while creating url.

No need to mention controller name as you are creating url from controller object.

```
<a href="<?php echo Yii::app()->controller->createUrl('switchLanguage',array('language'=>'en')); ?>">English</a>
```

Comment: using: Yii::app()->createUrl('language/switchLanguage',array('language'=>'en')); then url return: localhost/newapp/language/switchLanguage?language=en. how to change url return look like this: localhost/newapp/language/switchLanguage/language/en

Comment: please check this url: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url#user-friendly-urls

Comment: @Toàn Have you fixed your problem?

Comment: Then accept the solution which helped you fix the problem. This may be helpful for others.

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating Url like this, I mean using **controller**

```
Yii::app()->controller->createUrl('switchLanguage',array('language'=>'en'));
```

then you do not need to tell the createUrl about the controller name. just pass the action Name without the **action keyword** as **kumar_v has said**.

---

The above statement is similar to 
`$this->createUrl('switchLanguage',array('language'=>'en'));` 
here the **$this** is the object of the current controller, so here also **you do not need** to tell **createUrl()** about the **controller name**
**Note:-** The view should be of the same controller.

---

But if you are creating urls like

```
Yii::app()->createUrl('language/switchLanguage',array('language'=>'en'));
```

then **you need to tell the createUrl()** method about the controller as well as action (but without action Keyword :) )

#### Update

In your **config/main.php**
Uncomment the following portion

```
'urlManager'=>array(
            'urlFormat'=>'path',
            'rules'=>array(
                '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            ),
        ),
```

Comment: using: Yii::app()->createUrl('language/switchLanguage',array('language'=>'en')); then url return: localhost/newapp/language/switchLanguage?language=en. how to change url return look like this: localhost/newapp/language/switchLanguage/language/en